# getting the count of date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to get the count of a week day within a month using angularJS.
for example getting the count of Saturdays in the month.
how can i get it? 
Thank you 
here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="getdates()">
   <p ng-if="x='Sat'">{{dates.length}}</p>
   <div ng-repeat="x in dates">
    <input type="checkbox" ><p ng-show="x">{{x | format:'ddd'}}</p></input>
  </div>

</div>
  <script>



angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.dates=[];
  $scope.getdates=function(){
    for(i=0;i<31;i++){
      $scope.myDate = i+' Feb 2015 00:00:00 GMT';
      $scope.dates.push($scope.myDate)
    }
  };

})
.filter('format', function() {
  return function(input, format) {
    return moment(new Date(input)).format(format);
  };
})
;
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the following way:

## GET/INIT:

- get the date as an argument
- get the year and the month of the input (yearVar, monthVar)
- get the last day of that month (last_day_of_month)

## THEN

- starting from the first day `var currDate = new Date(yearVar, monthVar, 1)`

  find the first occurrence of the needed day `if(currDate.getDay() == 6)` (6 is sunday)
- remember this value, multiple if until the day is less than last_day_of_month

### DATE API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date